# Как отключить проект в Intellij Idea от Git

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, git-commit

Написал некий код на Intellij Idea и экспортировал это на Git. Потом увидел, что экспортировалось даже то, что не нужно (проект один, но в разных packages совершенно разные программы), так как только учусь.
Удалил этот репозиторий из Git, но до сих пор к нему подключена и при попытке закомитить пишет, что репозиторий не найден (что естественно). Так вот, как сделать, чтобы мой проект больше не был привязан к Version Control, так как это было изначально? В настройках не нашел подобной фичи

Answer (score 6):

В настройках раздел *Version Control* .

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кликните на директорию, с которой вы синхронизировали Git ( на скриншоте это *D:\Projects\OutgoingManager*) и нажмите на красный минус справа (он станет красным, когда выберете директорию).

Answer (score 2):

В папке с проектом папка **.idea**. Заходишь туда, ишешь файл **vcs.xml** и удаляешь оттуда строчку с папкой, которую ты хочешь убрать.

Answer (score 0):

Командная строка (терминал в Android Studio):

Windows:

```
rd /s /q ".git"
```

На Linux/Mac, вы можете использовать sudo , чтобы удалить его (в зависимости от разрешений).

Linux/Mac:

```
rm -rf .git
```